# Spring Cloud Function deployed as Azure function: Logging?

Tags: java, azure-functions, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I'm trying to map a Function Bean to an Azure function using Spring Cloud Function 2.0. How is logging supposed to be done?

Do I need to use the Azure context logger or a generic logger like slf4j?

There seems no way to get hold of the Azure context logger, once in the Function Bean.

However, when using slf4j the logging seems to work only locally, but when deploying to Azure and running from Azure portal - the logging doesn't appear in the Azure console.

Comment: I say this is probably a missing feature, so please consider raising an issue in [spring-cloud-function issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues)

Comment: Just and FYI, the [feature was added](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/265)